# I've two modals on a page, (i'm using bootstrap); clicking on any modal opens only the first. I don't understand js; is there an html fix?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

This is the code for the first modal; all that changes in the next two modals is the image links inside, but only these show up.

```
<div id="modallinkleft">
  <a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal">
  <img src="mylinks/cp/117s.jpg">
  <img src="mylinks/cp/23s.jpg">
  <img src="mylinks/cp/08s.jpg">
  </a>
  <div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-body">
      <img src="mylinks/cp/117.jpg">
      <img src="mylinks/cp/23.jpg">
      <img src="mylinks/cp/08.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Code you pasted shows only one modal.... Please paste complete html...

Comment: Why don't you even check if the content is displayed correctly as expected?

Comment: Where is the second modal? And you have your `<a>` shared with all the images, thereby I see only one single `<a>` tag.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Each **modal** should be given a **different id** and **each link** should be **targeted to a different modal id**.
So it should be something like that:

```
<a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal">
...
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"></div>
...
<a href="#myModal2" data-toggle="modal">
...
<div id="myModal2" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"></div>
...
```

In this way, if you click the first link, it should pop-up the first modal and if you click the second - the second modal is popped up.

Comment: can you help me on this? I have 2 modals as well but the other modal showing on page load. I am using `data-target` to each modal and using different `id` but still having problem :( @graumanoz

Answer (score 3):

There's a bug in the Bootstrap code. I am also having the same issue and my ids for the two modal are different, yet only the first one is launched. When I remove the first one from index.html, then the second modal structure comes alive.

The workaround I used is make a function that appends the modal to the body and then pass into the difference between the two modals to be filled in dynamically. Then call function whenever you need the modal.

i.e

```
 function appendModuleToBody(title){      
        $('#myModal1').remove(); // remove previously appended ones if needed
        $('#myModal2').remove();
        $( "body" ).append( ` -- modal html here -- ` }
```