# How to echo different data from different rows from my database using modal dialog?

Tags: php, html

I have a data displaying table that have a link(Reserver's Profile) which pops up a modal dialog that is expected to display data from the database basing on each rows. 
In my case the modal dialog displays the data on the first row in my database even when i click on the link on the second row and on any other row.

```
<tbody>       
    <?php
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM general_reservation ");
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
echo "<b><center><h3>Cars Reserved By Districts</h3></center></b><br><br>";

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    ?>

    <tr>
         <td><center><input type="checkbox" name="check[<?php echo $row['reservation_id'];?>]" value="1" ></center> </td>

           <td><input type="" name="car_type[]" value="<?php echo $row['car_type'];?>" readonly></label></td>
            <td><input style="width: 100px" type="" name="trim[]" value="<?php echo $row['trim'];?>" readonly></label></td>
            <td><input style="width: 80px" type="" name="year_made[]" value="<?php echo $row['year_made'];?>" readonly></label></td>
            <td><input style="width: 80px" type="" name="km[]" value="<?php echo $row['km'];?>" readonly></label></td>
            <td><input style=" background-color:<?php echo $row['exterior_colour'];?>; width: 55px;" type="" name=" exterior_colour[]" value="" readonly></label></td>
            <td><input type="" name="options[]" value="<?php echo $row['options'];?>" readonly></label></td>
            <td><input style="width: 65px" type="" name="quantity[]" value="<?php echo $row['quantity'];?>" readonly></label></td>
            <td><input type="" name="time[]" value="<?php echo $row['time'];?>" readonly></label></td>
            <td><textarea  type="" name="comment[]" value="<?php echo $row['comment'];?>" readonly><?php echo $row['comment'];?></textarea></td>
            <td><a  type="submit"  class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" >Reserver's Profile</a></td>

  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title"><center>Reserver</center></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
           <p >First Name: <?php echo $row['fname'];?> </p><br>
           <p >Last Name: <?php echo $row['lname'];?></p><br>
           <p >Mobile Number: <?php echo $row['mobile_number'];?></p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> 
  </div>


    </tr>

    <?php } //end of while loop ?>

    </tbody>
```

Comment: place the modal outside the table. when you call the modal, you want to use ajax to pull the profile from database, fill in the modal and show it.

Comment: After placing the modal outside the table, the modal dialog pop ups without the data from the database. How do i fix that?@mdamia

Comment: use js to pull the profile from the database asynchronously. placing the modal inside the loop will generate as many modals as your result's count. If that's the solution you intend to use, assign the reserver's id to the  button calling the modal data-target=reserversid and the modal id should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

You need unique id's for the modals, then update:

```
 data-target="#myModal"
```

For example create a variable above the row loop:

```
$i = 0;
while ( ... )
    # increment the pointer in the loop:

    $modal_id = 'myModal' . $i;
    $i ++;
```

Then append this unique id to each of the modal

```
 data-target="#<?php echo $modal_id; ?>"
```

and

```
<div class="modal fade" id="<?php echo $modal_id; ?>" role="dialog">
```

note: using Ajax would be better, though it's a more advanced technique.

Comment: How to i use unique id's for the modals? will be glad if can you illustrate. @Kevin Seitert

Comment: Im still having the same issue with your illustration. I wish to use Ajax but i have less idea of how to solve it with Ajax.

Comment: maybe first try getting this to work with static html.  For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16494227/ive-two-modals-on-a-page-im-using-bootstrap-clicking-on-any-modal-opens-on.  then make sure the dynamically generated html looks the same.